# C++ SDL2:2D tilemap with every tile has its own behavior

Tags: c++, 2d, rendering, tilemap, sdl2

I am working on 2D tile based game. 
I want to render the **tilemap** from a file but every tile has its own **behavior** 
for example: 
 **magmablock : poorlava();**
 **slimeblock : knockback();**

I have this files 
**Tile**, (**magmablock**;**slimeblock**;**iceblock**)(just examples and they inherit from tile ) ,**handler**

This is what I did I loaded the map in class with an array in every character 
i create a **tile** object in an array and give it an **ID**
in the **tile constructor**i do a **switch** statement if the ID is *1* for example create **magmablock** and i call the *deconstruct* so the **tiles array** will be empty

in the **magmablock** class i add **magmablock** object(this) to a **handler** class which update them and render them 
**this is the codes so u can understand more**

**levels.h**

```
#ifndef LEVELS_H
#define LEVELS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "tile.h"
using namespace std;

vector< vector<tile> > tiles;

class levels
{
public:

    static void loadworld(string levelfile)
    {
        int mw = 0,mh = 0;
        string tempNum;
        ifstream readLevel(levelfile);
        string mapCode;

        //i read from file i get the width and height (mw,mh) and the array
        //here i loop in the array

                for (int j = 0 ; j <= mh ; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i <= mw; i++)
                    {                   
                                tile t(stoi(tempNum),i,j); 
    //tempnum is the ID 
    //it's not important here
    //so i deleted it so the code will not be complicated

                                tiles[j][i] = t; //j - i
    // i create tile object in the array
                    }
                }
    }
};

#endif // LEVELS_H
```

**tile.cpp**

```
#include "tile.h"
#include "magma.h"
#include "slimeblock.h"
#include "wall.h"

tile::tile(int id,int x,int y)
{
        switch (id)
        {
            case 001:
        {
                tile *wallBlock = new wall(x,y); //create new objects
        }
            case 002:
        {
                tile *magmaBlock = new magma(x,y);
        }
            case 003:
        {
                tile *slime = new slimeblock(x,y);
        }
            default:
                break;
        }

        this->~tile(); // here i destroy it
}
```

**magmablock.cpp**

```
#include "magma.h"
#include "game.h"

magma::magma(int x,int y)
{
    this->id = magmaID;
    this->tileID = tile::tileID;
    tile::tileID++;
    this->tex = game::textures[0]; //this just load the texture

    this->crop.x = 32; //its texture from the spritesheet
    this->crop.y = 0;

    this->pos.x = x*32; // its position 
    this->pos.y = y*32;

    game::hand->addTile(this); // hand is the handler
}

void wall::init(){}

void wall::tick(){}

void wall::render(SDL_Renderer *ren)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren,tex,&crop,&pos);
}
```

**handler.h**

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H
#define HANDLER_H

#include "tile.h"
#include <vector>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

class handler
{
    public:

    handler(SDL_Renderer* ren){this->rend = ren;}

    SDL_Renderer* rend;

    vector<tile> tiles;

    /// Insert The  Tile ///

    void addTile(tile t)
    {
        tiles.push_back(t);
    }

    /// Destroy  The Tile ///

    void removeTile(tile t)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < tiles.size();i++)
        {
                if(tiles[i].tileID = t.tileID)
                {
                    tiles.erase(tiles.begin() + i);
                    tiles[i].destroy();
                }
        }
    }

    void init()
    {

    }

    void tick()
    {
        /// Tile Tick

        for(int i = 0;i < tiles.size();i++)
        {
            tiles[i].tick();
        }

        /// Tile Tick

        for(int i = 0;i < objects.size();i++)
        {
            objects[i].tick();
        }
    }

    void render()
    {
          for(int i = 0;i < tiles.size();i++)
        {

            tiles[i].render(rend);
        }
    }
};

#endif // HANDLER_H
```

Hope you understand me i know that this is too much 
but I didn't find another way to describe it.

**is this a good way?** 
**how to do it?**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more an opinion-based question but here are my thought (I'm not a C++ expert):

- Create a base class **Tile** that will handle generic stuff like rendering, animations if any, behavior of the tile...
- For each of your special tiles, create a new class that inherits from your base class **Tile** and override the behavior if your new tile has a custom behavior, or override the animation/render if it is a special case.
- Read the level file, and based on these informations, create your level and handle special cases like you did it.

To store the level you can either store it in a text file with special characters or if you need more data (i.e. a magma block can have different levels of damage done) I would take a shot at JSON or XML serialization. That way you can encode full objects to a file and read them directly as an array of tiles, it would make your method **loadworld** obsolete and you will have to just deserialize your JSON/XML file into a map.

This is what your level could looks like as a JSON file :

```
{
    "levelName" : "Level 1",
    "tiles" : [
        [{"type": "magma", "damages": 2}, {"type": "wall","color": "blue"}],
        [{"type": "floor"}, {"type": "floor"}]
    ]
}
```

This would translate to :

```
MW
FF
```

But you are able to pass in data into your tile objects.

I invite you to read a little bit more about [Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/) and [Polymorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-c/) in C++ if you are not so familiar with it.

I also think that the most used JSON library out there is [this one](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Comment: but how i can add the special tiles to the level 
u mean like this  
```cplusplus
for (int j = 0 ; j <= mh ; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i <= mw; i++)
                    {                   
 switch (id)
        {
            case 001:
        {
                tile *wallBlock = new wall(x,y); //create new objects
        }
            case 002:
.
```

Comment: So, using JSON or XML files you can take advantage of what we call deserialization (extracting a data structure from a series of bytes). You encode your special tiles in the JSON file and when you deserialize it, you will have your tilemap with the special tiles. 
I'll install a c++ compiler now and try to give you a more visual exemple of that process :)

Comment: ok sir 
ty for your time 
i am waiting for result